# Is it an issue for background checks, if my previous employer designation is different?

Tags: software-industry, india

I have a total of 4 years of experience and so far I have changed organization twice. Until recently, I have been working at Company A, however I have resigned due to personal reasons.

I have received an offer from another Company B as a Java Developer. My worry is that in Company A, I joined as an Android developer and within 2 months I was changed to the Java platform but in my payslip it's showing my Designation as an Executive and my Functional Title as an Android developer. Should I expect this to be a problem to show as an Android developer in my Company A payslip, and if so - what steps can I take to mitigate this?

Comment: They just verify if you had been a bonafide employee from the last company. The small discrepancy can be explained as people often move projects and while rare, tech changes also happen.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one answer to this question as policies for background checks vary from employer to employer.

I will note that it is very common for job titles to be meaningless and not conform to actual job that was done.  In my company, we try to speak with the previous supervisor to confirm the job duties.  However, there are many companies out there where the HR department advises that the only information they are allowed to provide for background checks is to confirm dates of employment.

If you've already received an offer, that probably means that Company B has seen your value via an interview.  Try not to stress about it and just be prepared to answer any questions from Company B if necessary to finalize your new position.

Answer (score 2):

No, this really does not matter. If you can prove the expertise on the particular domain you have applied for, and you can prove the employment (not the specific designation related to technology) - that should be enough.

The company internal functional title hardly matters.

Comment: Thanks Sourav, I already proved and i got offer from that organization