# Is it an issue for background checks, if my previous organization designation is different?

Tags: india, title, software

Recently i got offer letter from one of the MNC organization as **Java Developer** position and My previous Employer i joined as **Android developer** but after 2 months i was switched to Java projects in my previous organization but problem is in my previous employer payslip Functional title showing as **Android Developer**.Should I expect this to be a problem to show as an **Android developer** in my previous payslip, and if so - what steps can I take to mitigate this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it an issue for background checks, if my previous employer designation is different?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/149940/is-it-an-issue-for-background-checks-if-my-previous-employer-designation-is-dif)